# mechanize streaming download python

Tags: python, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am trying to download files from a site that requires htaccess - style authentication as well as a cookie, and am using python mechanize to download these files. is there a way to start writing before loading the whole file into memory?

edit: I'm using a mechanize.Browser to keep track of the auth/cookie, so either I need a way to use the Browser state when calling urlopen or a better way to user Browser.

edit2: wound up rewriting using urllib2, but am still mildly curious if there was an easy solution.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) to make the http connection, the answer is yes.  [`urlopen()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) returns a file-like object, from which you can read() chunks of data that can be written to disk one at a time.

Comment: can i get the cookies and auth headers from mechanize.Browser into urllib2? otherwise I'm not sure how urlopen helps.